# mysql function definer security

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about access control/best practices in MySQL. I have a Database set up for a website. This database holds user login info and general customer/product info.  I have separated the information into secure and un-secure information and created 2 schemas for them.  Schema A holds non-secure info such as customer name, shopping cart, product names, prices etc.  Schema B holds secure info such as uid, encrypted password, salt.  I have a weblogin user that is utilized by the server-side scripting to access the database and have limited it's permissions to schema A. I then have a set of functions/procedures to register/validate/update passwords so the weblogin user can perform these functions without having access to the information in schema B.

So, my question is 2-fold
A: does it make any difference in security to have the stored procedures/functions in schema A or B?  Weblogin does not have drop/create access so in theory should not be able to modify them to do anything nefarious. I just would like to know if there are any gotchas with putting them in the A when they are accessing data in B, or putting them in B but having to GRANT EXECUTE permissions on them to weblogin.  AKA which is more secure, or am I being pendantic?

B: for the user defined in the proc/func is root acceptable?
ex: `CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`PROCEDURE`validate_user``
Or should I create a separate user with granted access to that data for the definer?

I am looking for answers from anyone who knows any peculiarities about how these permissions work.   It would seem as though there is no difference between them, but I am aware things aren't always what they seem.  I am still learning about web security and trying to apply best practices wherever I can.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> The DEFINER clause determines the security context to be used when checking access privileges .

```
    CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE procedureName
```

> will set the definer to be the current user. You can write a stored procedure/ routines without using "DEFINER". You may find in detail at:
>   http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/access-control-in-mysql-stored-routines-by-example-definer-invoker-sql-security

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, one can specify execution privileges by adding the following statement in the procedure body (after declaration):
**SQL SECURITY INVOKER**

Example:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_add_user`()
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
(...)
```

Doing so, the actual invoker privileges are applied and the DEFINER part is omitted (even when it is auto-added during schema import).
Full reference here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-objects-security.html